# Counting random common subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let $X,Y\sim\mathrm{Unif}(\{0,1\}^N)$ be random bit strings, and define $C_k$ to be the number of length-$k$ common sub-sequences between:
$$
C_k:=\sum_{(i_1,\dots,i_k),(j_1,\dots,j_k)\in \mathcal{I}}\mathbb{1}\{x_{i_1,\dots,i_k}=y_{j_1,\dots,j_k}\}, \qquad \mathcal{I}:=\{(i_1,\dots,i_k)\in[N]^k: i_1<\dots<i_k\}
$$

It's rather straightforward to show $\mathbb{E} C_k =\binom{n}{k}^2 2^{-k}$, by the linearity of expectation. However, can we bound the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E} (C_{k}| C_{\alpha k}= 0)$, where $\alpha\in\{2,3,\dots\}$?

Combinatorial interpretation: if the longest common sub-sequence between two random strings is $\alpha k$, what are the expected number of length-$k$ common subsequences?